# SQL Server datetime data, Out-of-range value error

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I am getting the following error from this piece of code

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 3
>   The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

T-SQL:

```
datediff(dd, a.ContractStartDate, 
    cast(case when isdate(
       cast(datepart(month, dateadd(mm, 0, a.WarrStartDate)) as varchar(2)) + '/' +
       cast('00' + datepart(DAY, a.WarrStartDate) as varchar(2)) + '/' + 
       cast(datepart(year, dateadd(YEAR, case when a.TRSCustNO = 89555 then 2 else 3 end, a.WarrStartDate)) as varchar(4)))=0
           then          
         cast('00'+datepart(month,dateadd(mm,0,a.WarrStartDate))as varchar(2))+'/'+
         cast('00'+datepart(DAY,dateadd(dd,-1,a.WarrStartDate)) as varchar(2)) +'/'+ 
         cast(datepart(year,dateadd(YEAR,case when a.TRSCustNO = 89555 then 2 else 3 end 
   ,a.WarrStartDate))as varchar(4))
else
         cast('00'+datepart(month,dateadd(mm,0,a.WarrStartDate))as varchar(2))+'/'+
         cast('00'+datepart(DAY,a.WarrStartDate) as varchar(2)) +'/'+
         cast(datepart(year,dateadd(YEAR,case when a.TRSCustNO = 89555 then 2 else 3 end 
   ,a.WarrStartDate))as varchar(4)
                   ) end 
  as datetime) 
) as EarnDays
```

Comment: Begin by making sure that all your strings in the varchar=>datetime conversions are ALWAYS in the format YYYYMMDD.

Comment: So move the code that year then month then date?? I have done this and it still hasn't worked

Comment: I think @Alejandro is saying use the ISO date format for the text strings so that date doesn't need to be converted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unless I am missing something, this can all be simplified like this. I didn't see a reason to be casting between date and varchar types.

```
case 
when datediff(dd,a.ContractStartDate, 
              dateadd(year,(case when a.TRSCustNO = 89555 then 2 else 3 end), a.WarrStartDate)
          )=0
then 
     dateadd(year, (case when a.TRSCustNO = 89555 then 2 else 3 end), 
              dateadd(dd,-1,a.WarrStartDate)
     )
else
     dateadd(year, (case when a.TRSCustNO = 89555 then 2 else 3 end), a.WarrStartDate)  
end as EarnDays
```

Let me know if I missed the point of it.

If you want to know why you were getting the error, just don't cast it back to a date and look at the output.

Comment: Thanks that seemed to have worked and is easier. How do you mean about getting the error and checking it by casting back?

Comment: @amymon87 - I was just saying that if you were curious as to why you were getting the error, you could just not cast your varchar to a date. Just looking at it, it appears you were trying to cast the following types of values to date - '00/00/2014'. This is because you were doing '00' + day, but then just taking the first two characters (varchar(2)).

Comment: I see now what you mean - thanks very much for this!